# Android: How to record video and process its frames in real time?

Tags: android, camera

I have a SurfaceView and a MediaRecorder and I use to show and record a video. Now I want to access individual frames on this video in real time to do some processing with them. Can I get access to the frames via the MediaRecorder object? Or is there a listener that I have to add?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, MediaCodec might be better suited.  See e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest (requires Android 4.3).

Comment: I have 4.0.4. I want to get each frame run a computer vision algorithm on each frame and show the results in real time.

Comment: Hey Mohammad, did you ever find the answer for this?

Comment: have you got a solution to this question?